# How to wait for a future to complete in Flutter widget test?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

I am trying to perform a widget test, specifically navigation test. I am using bloc architecture, setting a stream on the bloc triggers a series of events inside the bloc, gets session info from the server call (which returns a future of session info object), on successful server call a login stream is set and the widget has a stream subscription to this stream and navigates to the next screen.

I am using mockito to mock the server call and stubbing the server call to return a future of success response. The problem is the when I am calling `pumpAndSettle()` it is getting timed out as it is not waiting for the future to complete and return the success response.

I apologize if I am not making it very clear, but here is the sample code:

**login_bloc.dart**

```
class LoginBloc {
  LoginRepository _loginRepository;
  final String searchKeyword = "special-keyword";

  final _urlString = PublishSubject<String>();
  final _isLoggedIn = BehaviorSubject<bool>(seedValue: false);
  final _errorMessage = PublishSubject<String>();

  Observable<bool> get isLoggedIn => _isLoggedIn.stream;
  Observable<String> get isErrorState => _errorMessage.stream;

  LoginBloc({LoginRepository loginRepository})
      : _loginRepository = loginRepository ?? LoginRepository() {
          // Listen on the _urlString stream to call the function which checks for the special keyword and if a match is found make a server call
    _urlString.stream.listen((String url) {
      _authorizationFullService(url);
    });
  }

    // Search for special keyword and if a match is found call the server call function
  void _authorizationFullService(String url) {
    if (url.contains(searchKeyword)) {
      int index = url.indexOf(searchKeyword);
      String result = url.substring(index + searchKeyword.length);
      result = result.trim();
      String decodedUrl = Uri.decodeFull(result);
      if (decodedUrl != null && decodedUrl.length > 0) {
        _fullServiceServerCall(decodedUrl);
      } else {
        _isLoggedIn.sink.add(false);
      }
    }
  }

    // Call server call function from repository which returns a future of the Authorization object
  void _fullServiceServerCall(String decodedUrl) {
    _loginRepository
        .getSession(decodedUrl)
        .then(_handleSuccessAuthorization)
        .catchError(_handleErrorState);
  }

    // Handle success response and set the login stream
  void _handleSuccessAuthorization(Authorization authorization) {
    if (authorization != null && authorization.idnumber != 0) {
      _isLoggedIn.sink.add(true);
    } else {
      _isLoggedIn.sink.add(false);
    }
  }

    // Handle error response and set the error stream
  void _handleErrorState(dynamic error) {
    _isLoggedIn.sink.add(false);
    _errorMessage.sink.add(error.toString());
  }

  void dispose() {
    _urlString.close();
    _isLoggedIn.close();
    _errorMessage.close();
  }
}
```

**widget_test.dart**

```
group('Full Login Navigation test', () {
    LoginRepository mockLoginRepository;
    LoginBloc loginBloc;
    NotificationBloc notificationBloc;
    NavigatorObserver mockNavigatorObserver;
    Authorization _auth;
    String testUrl;

    setUp(() {
      mockLoginRepository = MockLoginRepository();
      _auth = Authorization((auth) => auth
        ..param1 = "foo"
        ..param2 = "bar"
        ..param3 = "foobar"
        ..param4 = "barfoo");
      loginBloc = LoginBloc(loginRepository: mockLoginRepository);
      mockNavigatorObserver = MockNavigatorObserver();
      testUrl = "http://test.test.com";
    });

    Future<Null> _buildFullLoginPage(LoginBloc loginBloc,
        NotificationBloc notificationBloc, WidgetTester tester) async {
      when(mockLoginRepository.getSession(testUrl))
          .thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(_auth));
      await tester.pumpWidget(LoginBlocProvider(
        child: NotificationBlocProvider(
          child: MaterialApp(
            home: LoginFullService(),
            onGenerateRoute: NavigationRoutes.routes,
            navigatorObservers: [mockNavigatorObserver],
          ),
          notificationBloc: notificationBloc,
        ),
        loginBloc: loginBloc,
      ));
      //TODO: Remove casting to dynamic after dart sdk bug fix: https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/163
      verify(mockNavigatorObserver.didPush(any, any) as dynamic);
      loginBloc.getAuthorization(
          "http://testing.testing.com?search-keyword=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.test.com");
    }

    testWidgets('Navigate to landing page on correct login url',
        (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await _buildFullLoginPage(loginBloc, notificationBloc, tester);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      expect(find.byKey(Key('webview_scaffold')), findsNothing);
      //TODO: Remove casting to dynamic after dart sdk bug fix: https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/163
      verify(mockNavigatorObserver.didPush(any, any) as dynamic);
    });
});
```

On running the widget test the `tester.pumpAndSettle()` inside `testWidgets` times out before the future is completed. This is the error log:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown running a test:
pumpAndSettle timed out

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      WidgetTester.pumpAndSettle.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:299:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:69:41)
#4      WidgetTester.pumpAndSettle (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:295:27)
#5      main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/ssiddh/Documents/projects/mobile-flutter/test/ui/pages/login/login_full_test.dart:114:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:72:23)
#7      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:555:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:539:14)
#11     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:883:24)
#17     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:880:15)
#18     testWidgets.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:71:22)
#19     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test/src/backend/declarer.dart:168:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#20     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks.<anonymous closure> (package:test/src/backend/invoker.dart:249:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#25     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks (package:test/src/backend/invoker.dart:246:5)
#26     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test/src/backend/declarer.dart:166:33)
#31     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure> (package:test/src/backend/declarer.dart:165:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#32     Invoker._onRun.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test/src/backend/invoker.dart:403:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#46     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
#47     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
#48     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:169:12)
(elided 30 frames from class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, and package stack_trace)
```

I would really appreciate any kind of help or feedback.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try wrapping your test with

```
testWidgets('Navigate to landing page on correct login url',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.runAsync(() async {

      // test code here

    });
 });
```

Comment: You just saved my day! Cheers!

Comment: can you pls explain your solution?

Comment: Flutter test uses fakeAsync, which means Futures/Streams are not executed without some additional push. This allows it for tests that for example wait some time (delay) to pretend the time has already passed. This allows unit tests to run much faster. But without this they'll wait forever. `runAsync` restores the "normal" behavior. I hope I got that right, it's a while I had a closer look.

Comment: hey can you please tell me a way that I can await my Api response and a bool flag value is true then do sth,how  can I do this in widgettest

Comment: @Bunny1367 please create a new question with more information

Comment: If you don't want to add runAsync to every widget test, you can use a simple wrapper for that:
`void testWidgetsAsync(String desc, Future<void> Function(WidgetTester tester) test) => testWidgets(desc, (tester) async => await tester.runAsync(() async => await test(tester)));`